# Вывод на печать RichEditBox.Document

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

UWP Windows 10

Пытаюсь сделать печать текста из `RichEditBox`.

Нашел пример реализации печати на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204545.aspx) однако тут печатается контрол - как скриншот. Ведь `RichEditBox.Document` может отдать форматированный RTF текст, как нормально распечатать весь текст из контрола?